# How to conditionally insert/remove host DOM element in angular 2 directive

Tags: angular, web-component, angular2-directives

I want to create a directive that will decide whether should or should not its host element apppear on the page. Ideally I would like it to remove the element from the DOM and not just hide/show it with css. Usecase is:

```
<ul role="navigation">
  <li><a>public link</a></li>
  <li><a>public link2</a></li>
  <li access="admin"><a>admin-only link</a></li>
</ul>
```

It would use UserService to get currentUser roles and if there's no **admin** there the `li` would be removed.

I suppose I could achieve the same effect with `ng-if` (if it's still available in angular 2) by passing the expression to evaulate in the main component. But with the directive it is more semantic and elegant.

Is it possible?

```
import {Directive} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Directive({
    selector: 'access'
})
export class Access {
 //what goes here
}
```

I could've easily done that in angular 1 (inside directive's `compile` function), but how can I do this in Angular 2?

Comment: I've added a directive in my github repo here, https://github.com/IbraheemAlSaady/angular-role-restrict-directive/tree/master/angular2
the code is a little bit different of what you want, but it could help you build your own.

Answer (score 11):

This implementation will be similar to what ngIf directive is. And the Angular [guide for structural directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html) (which you plan to create too) gives an example of `myUnless` that just reverses `ngIf`.

You implementation for access will look similar to the `myUnless` implementation.

```js
@Directive({ selector: '[access]' })
export class AccessDirective {
  constructor(
    private _templateRef: TemplateRef,
    private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) { }
  @Input() set myUnless(condition: boolean) {
    if (condition) {
      this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._templateRef);
    } else {
      this._viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

And use it like:

```html
<li *access="isAdmin"><a>admin-only link</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing an element from the DOM is done with the `*ngIf` directive.

But if you really insist on using your own directive, I believe [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ElementRef-class.html) is the way to go. Even though I would not advice on using this

You will get something like this:

```
import {Directive} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Directive({
  selector: '[access]' //this is how you address an attribute directive
})
export class Access {
  constructor(private _userService : UserService, private _elementRef : ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._checkAdmin();
  }   

  private _checkAdmin() : void {
    if(!this._userService.currentUser.hasRole('admin')) {
      let el : HTMLElement = this._elementRef.nativeElement;
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you advise not to do this?

Comment: because, in such a simple thing as this, `*ngIf` is way more intuitive, and leaves the DOM editing to angular

Comment: I need to access value of the `access` attribute but in the constuructor it is not yet available  - it's `undefined`

Comment: I've edit my answer. I believe you have to use the ngOnInit function. This is called after the constructor and after attribute binding has finished

Comment: The Attribute Directive guide warns against direct DOM manipulation, e.g., use of `removeChild()`: "Manipulating the DOM directly is a practice we'd rather avoid because it chains us to the browser DOM API... The rendering phase could be offloaded to a Web Worker for faster performance. Our directive might work when we ran the application outside the browser, perhaps on the server in a pre-render phase."

Comment: Had this same question and found this in the angular docs.  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html